# Unable to access PHP files in a subfolder on AWS Beanstalk [500 Error]

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded some php files to an elastic beanstalk instance `archive.zip`. I can access the index page fine on the browser however if I try to go directly to a file via the browser I am getting a `500` error. For example when I type in the browser `elasticbeanstalk.com/folder/filename.php` I encounter the error. This I assume is a permissions issue, how can I change the permissions on these files to make them accessible on the internet?

Comment: when you upload a .zip file elasticbeanstalk will unzip and copy into `/var/www/html`. Did you confirm it by command line?

Comment: If the problem are the permissions, these permissions would be set in the server config. You would have to specify which server you are using

Comment: @huythang I didn't confirm via command line but the logs said everything was uploaded successful and I can access the index.html on my site.

Comment: @wouter140 I am not seeing anywhere where I can change these permissions. Any idea as to where I can access them?

Comment: @KernElliott What server are you using?

Comment: @wouter140 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running PHP 5.6

Comment: @KernElliott why do you think this is a permission issue? what does the EB log say?

Comment: @tal the logs don't report an error.

Comment: @KernElliott you wrote that you get HTTP 500. that is a server error. i can't see how this is not in the logs. did you pull all of them?

Comment: @Tal I am having issues in accessing the logs I keep getting permission denied to open the folder